# How to convert a working rails contact form, into a bootstrap modal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, controller, modal-dialog, contact-form

I currently have a working rails contact form (taken from another SO answer), available on /contact, that uses a controller, model and mailer (Mandrill). It responds to new and create routes in the controller, and still uses activemodel features. The form does not use ajax.

I now need to try to make my contact form work on the home page, as opposed to the /contact page via a modal pop-up.

I have read a number of SO queries, about modals, but all seem to be connected with getting a modal to do something specific - and not so much on creating a modal form to mimic a normal form.

To start I added a working modal, to the homepage.

When I then try to add the form into the homepage model, I run into method errors as the form is part of the home_controller. After copying my new and create controller actions into my home controller, I realized, that the form is just hidden, and is still being run when the page loads (by the index action).
Adding `@message = Message.new` into the index action does not seem to help - and wouldn't I want this on the modal load ?

Here are the main moving parts of my working form from the contact page, and the working modal box from the homepage - how can I merge the two and retain the functionality I have ?

here is the contact controller:

```
#/app/controllers/contact_controller.rb
class ContactController < ApplicationController

 def new
  @message = Message.new
 end

 def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])

  if @message.valid?
     NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
     redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
  else
   flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
   render :new
  end

 end
end
```

the message model

```
#app/models/message.rb
class Message

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :subject, :body

  validates :name, :email, :subject, :body, :presence => true
  validates :email, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

And the view:

```
 <%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path do |form| %>
  <fieldset class="fields">
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :name %>
      <%= form.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :email %>
      <%= form.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :subject %>
      <%= form.text_field :subject %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :body %>
      <%= form.text_area :body %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="actions">
   <%= form.submit "Send" %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Finally within my home page I have this for the modal (not containing the form)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_contact_form">

  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
      <h3>Contact Form</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Test Content for Modal</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
 </div>
</div>
```

Which is called by this `<li><a href="#modal_contact_form" data-toggle="modal">contact</a></li>`

My attempts have been many and varied to get this working up until this point - the main issue I need to get my head around (I think) is that the form is loaded by the index action on the home_controller - Ideally I guess I still want to use the logic in my contact_controller ?

Any advice and suggestions appreciated - at this point I am wondering if there is an easy way just to move a form into a modal or not!

Cheers,

Mizpah

note: In response to queries I have about ajax, I have only avoided ajax due to perceived difficulty and lack of progress with trying it on rails 3.2 - I would be delighted to use it if it would actually be easier to turn this into an ajaxified form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was not far away after all!

After a pointer from #rubyonrails channel, the answer was:

1) To copy the form as is, into the modal. (note that different styling is probably needed - but this answer gives the functionality needed).

2) To add `@message = Message.new` into the index action on my home_controller.rb

I had tried something very similar to this, but must of introduced another error, and thus bypassed the correct solution.

Comment: How were their routes? Could you post here, please?